# Delayed start of Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater

Tags: prototype

In my web-app have a statusbar for my users where number of new messages etc is shown. I use `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater` for refreshing every 60 sec. But the `PeriodicalUpdater` is doing the first fetch on initialization when there is no need as the data is fresh on page load.

So what is your best practice to start the Updater 60 seconds after page load?

I am using a `window.setTimeout` to call a function that starts the updater, but is there something better?

```
function statusbarUpdate(){
  new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater({
    success: 'statusbar'
  }, '/status', {
    method: 'get',
    frequency: 60,
    decay: 1
  });
}
window.setTimeout("statusbarUpdate()", 1000 * 60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in [`Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater`'s source](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/1fb9728/src/ajax/periodical_updater.js#L209) that allows for a delayed start.

However for a bit of syntactic sugar the last line can be neatened:

```
statusbarUpdate.delay(1000 * 60);
```

Comment: Thank you twice: for the source where I can see that [line 220](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/1fb9728/src/ajax/periodical_updater.js#L220) is what annoys me: `this.start()` that starts the call immediately and for the [`delay()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/delay) method, that was new to me :-)

Comment: Looking again at the source and I realise there isn't much code there, you could make a copy and alter it so it doesn't start straight away.

Comment: that would be an option, but then I had to maintain that code on every prototype update (although I think there will not be much change in this function).

Comment: @clockworkgeek -- the source code shows this.start() at line 220.  Should your patch go before this line?  ie -- this.delay(1000*60); this.start();

Comment: Disregard both -- I should look at source post before commenting!